# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and have gone through several solutions on tackoverflow, but to no avail. It's still showing the same error of Cross-Origin Request Blocked.

```
$(".cmd_submit").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    //crossOrigin: true,
    //header:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'http://localhost/members/register',
    data: $('#form_reg').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
  alert(data);
    }
```

I also included this:

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

on my app.blade.php, but it still didn't work.

Comment: check your php code some time it happen due to syntex error in php code

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors for handling CORS in Laravel. If you still face issues, please include request and response headers.

Comment: It doesn't even go to the php file, because the url is the problem, it keeps returning error function instead of success function

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `config/cors.php` content.

Mine looks like this:

```php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */

    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry I was not very clear here. You need to install `barryvdh/laravel-cors` library first and it will allow `OPTIONS` request to get `200` response with needed headers. Laravel does not come with this package so Chrome (or any other modern browser) will see that Cross-Origin headers are missing and will block the request.

Comment: I just added the file cors.php now, and i run my code, not still working, is there anything else i need to do for it to get working?

Comment: Yes, read a comment above from jelhan. Install barryvdh/laravel-cors library and publish vendor files. Just follow the documentation on Github.

Comment: @chinnyenechukwu Sorry I was not very clear in my response. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The default path only comes with 'api/*' you need to add additional paths outside of 'api/*'